# Change the animation activation event

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Need to change the animation activation event. This animation is activated when the user double-clicks on `form1`. I need that the animation is triggered by double clicking on the component `webBrowser1` and by triggering `button1`.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
Timer tmr;
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.MouseDoubleClick += Form1_MouseDoubleClick;
    this.Paint += Form1_Paint;
    tmr = new Timer();
    tmr.Interval = 10;
    tmr.Tick += tmr_Tick;
}

int x;
int step = 5; 
void Form1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    tmr.Stop();
    x = 0;
    tmr.Start();
}

void tmr_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    x += step;
    if (x > this.Width)
    {
        x = 0;
        (sender as Timer).Stop();
    }
    this.Invalidate();  
}
void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Red, 0, 0, x, 4);
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of just handling the MouseDoubleClick Event you should also listen for webBrowser1 and button1. Something like this:

```
this.MouseDoubleClick += Form1_MouseDoubleClick;
webBrowser1.MouseDoubleClick += Form1_MouseDoubleClick;
//I dont know the exact method for the button but it should be similar to this:
button1.Click += Form1_MouseDoubleClick;
```